# Module build failed: TypeError: The plugin "transform-runtime" didn't export a Plugin instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Using Babel with Webpack and trying to get generators to work in some react code.  Attempting to use `babel-runtime` and `babel-plugin-transform-runtime` to enable the use of ES6 generators but I'm getting the following error message when I fire up my local dev server:

`Module build failed: TypeError: The plugin "transform-runtime" didn't export a Plugin instance`

My `package.json` includes the following

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "babel-core": "5.8.38",
    "babel-loader": "5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "6.11.0",
    "babel-runtime": "6.11.6",
    ...
 }
```

My `webpack.config.js` includes the following

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {
      ...
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        plugins: ['transform-runtime']
      }
    },
  ...
}
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
"babel-runtime": "6.11.6",
```

vs

```
"babel-core": "5.8.38",
```

Your versions don't match up. Since most of your deps are Babel 6, you should be using `babel-core@6`, same for `babel-loader`.